# Ionic2 / Typescript : normalize() doesn't work with iOS9 and below

Tags: typescript, ios8, ionic2, ios9

I'm using Ionic2 to create a android/ios application. I have a problem with ios8 and 9 versions, and I identified where the problem is, but I don't know how to solve it properly.

I use the normalize function to normalize a user input, but on iOS 8 and 9, it simply doesn't work (no error message), the code is not executed. I tried to simplify the code like that :

```
let uinput = 'éTelkhd sfhe lRR';
console.log('#1 -> ', uinput.toLowerCase());
console.log('#2 -> ', uinput.toLowerCase().normalize('NFD'));
```

the second log is never executed (even the #2 print). It works if I remove the normalize function.

Where this bug comes from ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `.normalize()` is only supported in `iOS 10` because its `es6` feature, check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) for the browsers compatibility, you can use this [polyfill](https://github.com/walling/unorm) in your project.

Note: this polyfill is a `NodeJS` based, you have to use [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or another module bundler so you can use it in the in the browsers based project